# Type mismatch when changing cell background color

Tags: vba, ms-word

I try to change the color of a cell, according to the value of a dropdown field.
This is my Code.

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()
Dim MyTable As Table
Set MyTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Dim CellStatus As String
Dim CellColor As String
CellStatus = ActiveDocument.FormFields("DropdownStatus").DropDown.Value
Select Case CellStatus
    Case 2
        CellColor = "wdRed"
    Case 3
        CellColor = "wdYellow"
    Case 4
        CellColor = "wdGreen"
End Select
MyTable.Cell(1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = CellColor
MsgBox CellColor
End Sub
```

I always get a type mismatch error on the line

```
MyTable.Cell(1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = CellColor
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the `BackgroundPatternColor` property to a string.  It needs to be set to a WdColor constant.

```
Dim CellColor As WdColor
Case 2
    CellColor = wdRed 'Remove the quotes
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223960(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're getting type missmatch because of using String instead of wdColor, try this:

```
Sub ChangeCellColor()
Dim MyTable As Table
Set MyTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Dim CellStatus As String
Dim CellColor As wdColor
CellStatus = ActiveDocument.FormFields("DropdownStatus").DropDown.Value
Select Case CellStatus
    Case 2
        CellColor = wdRed
    Case 3
        CellColor = wdYellow
    Case 4
        CellColor = wdGreen
End Select
MyTable.Cell(1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = CellColor
MsgBox CellColor
End Sub
```